# Bluetooth connection with Nokia e63 in java?

Tags: mobile, bluetooth, nokia-s40

I want to connect with my nokia e63 mobile using bluetooth or usb with pc but that using java application.

I want to know about how to do that ? 
 And
my question are like :

1. Can I connect with using java application and if yes then how ?
2. I mainly want to get the calling information. I want to save the calling information like whose called on which time in database but for that i need the number whose calling ? Is this possible with using java application ?

And any references will very much helpful.

Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

I developed an Bluetooth Java Applicaton 1 year ago and I 've used the Java Docs pretty much which are really helpful ! 
http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/bluetooth2/ , http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/bluetoothcore/

I don't know how to access call informations but connecting is not that difficult.